# Why it said its error in python using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello i want to make a YouTube downloader in python using tkinter but there's an error
the code is:

```
from  tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from  pytube import YouTube
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500+350+100")


def openpath():
    download_out.config(text="من الطبيعي عدم استجابة الكمبيوتر عند التحميل")
    font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold", 10, "bold")
    download_name.config(text="")
    download_size.config(text="")
    download_loc.config(text="")
    global direct
    direct=filedialog.askdirectory()
    path_holder.config(text = direct)
def Download():
    url = link_ent.get()
    Selceted= types.get()
    if len(url) < 1:
        link_error.config(text = "الرجاء ادخال موقع الفيديو")
    if len(direct) < 1:
        path_error.config(text = "الرجاء ادخال مكان تنزيل الملف")
    else:
        link.config(text="")
        path_error.config(text="")
        try:
            Yt = YouTube(url)
            try:
                if Selceted == options[0]:
                    typ = Yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                elif Selceted == options[1]:
                    typ = Yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
                else:
                    Yt.streams.get_audio_only()
            except:
                path_error.config(text="حدثت معنا اخطاء")
        except:
                path_error.config(text="الرجاء ادخال مكان تنزيل صالح!")


window.title("Youtube Downloader")
window.resizable(False,False)
window.config(bg = "gray3")
heading = Label(window, text = "برنامج تحميل الفيديوهات", background = "gray3",foreground = "dark 
orange",
            font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",20,"bold"))
 heading.pack(anchor="center",pady=10)
link = Label(window,text="الرابط",background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
link.pack(anchor="ne",padx=30,pady=25)
entry_url=StringVar()
link_ent=Entry(window,width=52,textvariable = entry_url)
link_ent.place(x=90,y=83)

link_error= Label(window,background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
link_error.place(x=300,y=110)
path =  Label(window,text="موقع الملف",background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
path.pack(anchor="ne",padx=30,pady=2)
path_holder= Label(window,text="\t\t\t",background="white",foreground="black",
         font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
path_holder.place(x=240,y=130)


path_style=ttk.Style()


path_style.configure("PT.TButton",background="DarkOrange1",foreground="DarkOrange1",
                 font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
path_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path " ,style="PT.TButton",command= 
openpath())
path_btn.place(x=323,y=156)

path_error= Label(window,text="Demo",background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
path_error.place(x=280,y=150)
Download_type=Label(window,text="أنواع التنزيل",background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
Download_type.pack(anchor="e",padx=30,pady=37)
options=["جودة عالية","جودة منخفضة","صوت فقط"]
types = ttk.Combobox(window,values=options,width=23)
types.current(0)
types.place(x=240,y=185)
ChooseType=Label(window,text="اختر النوع ",background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
ChooseType.place(x=170,y=187)


download_style=ttk.Style()


download_style.configure("DD.TButton",background="DarkOrange1",foreground="DarkOrange1",
                 font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",10))

Download_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "تحميل " ,style="PT.TButton")
Download_btn.pack(anchor="center",pady=30)

download_out=Label(window,text="طبيغي ان تظهر رسالة اللابتوب غير مستجيب أثناء 
التحميل",background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
             font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
download_out.pack(anchor="center",pady=30)


download_name=Label(window,background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
download_name.pack(anchor="ne",padx=30,pady=10)

download_size=Label(window,background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
download_size.pack(anchor="ne",padx=30,pady=10)


download_loc=Label(window,background="gray3",foreground="dark orange",
         font = ("Bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
download_loc.pack(anchor="ne",padx=30,pady=10)



window.mainloop()
```

and error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 72, in <module>
    path_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path " ,style="PT.TButton",command= openpath())
  File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 10, in openpath
    download_out.config(text="من الطبيعي عدم استجابة الكمبيوتر عند التحميل")
NameError: name 'download_out' is not defined`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont define `download_out` until line 100, however you call `openpath()` on line 73, so your calling this function before you have defined `download_out`. This function `openpath`  first line is referncing `download_out` as this function is called before you define `download_out` is why you get the error saying its not defined

If you want to use `download_out` inside the function `openpath` then you need to define `download_out` before you call `openpath()`. Are you sure you mean to call `openpath` on line 100 or just pass a reference to it?

I suspect you want to change this line

```py
path_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path ",style="PT.TButton",command=openpath())
```

to

```py
path_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path ",style="PT.TButton",command=openpath)
```

So your passing a reference to openpath rather than the result of executing openpath

Answer (score 0):

Using wrong value for option `command` in a `Button`, it should be a function name to call when button click, not result of a function.

In your code, function will be called when button defined befor variable `download_out` defined.

```py
#path_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path " ,style="PT.TButton",command=openpath())
path_btn  = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path " ,style="PT.TButton",command=openpath)
```

Answer (score -1):

since download_out was declared as global variable you should use the reserved word `global` in order to use it from within the function `openpath`

```
global download_out
download_out.config(text="من الطبيعي عدم استجابة الكمبيوتر عند التحميل")
```

Comment: where should i but this?

Comment: @BaraaJawish I am sorry but I dont understand your question.

Comment: i said you answered a code :global download_out
download_out.config(text="من الطبيعي عدم استجابة الكمبيوتر عند التحميل")
but where i will put this in my codes?

Comment: Yes. I have posted  code snippet. What is your question? Did you try it? Did it solve the problem?

Comment: yes i try it but i dont know where i put it at code 10 or 100

Comment: you dont need to define a variable as global in a function to use it. only if you wanted to reassign the value of it. However in this case thats not relevant, the issue here is that the call to execute the function happens before download_out has ever been defined.

Comment: it should be used in  `openpath`